# How to add the timer in flutter app while answer the question

Tags: android, ios, oop, flutter, dart

Greeting!
Im new to flutter and dart, currently I'm working on the quiz application in flutter, I want to add the timer functionality in the application and calculate the time of each question.

Comment: Did one of the answers help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `quiver` package, here is a simple example:

```
class QuizPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _QuizPageState createState() => _QuizPageState();
}

class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String answer;
  int seconds;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    seconds = 60;
    startTimer();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('QuizPage'),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Question?'),
            Text('Seconds left: $seconds'),
            TextFormField(
              onSaved: (result) =>  answer = result,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Answer!'),
              onPressed: seconds != 0 ? (){
                _formKey.currentState.save();
                print(answer);
              } : null,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void startTimer(){
    CountdownTimer(Duration(seconds: seconds), Duration(seconds: 1)).listen((data){
    })..onData((data){
      setState(() {
        seconds--;
      });
    })..onDone((){
      setState(() {
        seconds = 0;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Here you can answer in 60 seconds, but when the time is up, the button will no longer work.

**And vice versa**

Also, you can calculate time from 0 and stop the timer after the answer:

```
class QuizPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _QuizPageState createState() => _QuizPageState();
}

class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String answer;
  Timer timer;
  int seconds;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    seconds = 0;
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
      setState(() {
        seconds++;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('QuizPage'),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Question?'),
            Text('Seconds passed: $seconds'),
            TextFormField(
              onSaved: (result) =>  answer = result,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Answer!'),
              onPressed:(){
                timer?.cancel();
                _formKey.currentState.save();
                print(answer);
                print('In $seconds seconds');
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What advantages would a server timer (using websocket or something) have over this client-side timer (if any)? or is there no advantage at all?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, 
this starts off from 60

```
int t = 60;
countDown(){
  Future.doWhile(()async {
    //this changes the value by -1 every second until it reaches zero
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1),);
    setState(() {
      //add text widget in your build method which takes t as the data
      t--;
    });
    return t!=0;
  });
}
```

call the method countDown when you want the timer to begin